# Set read status of getstream.io notification feed via rest api or php sdk

Tags: getstream-io

I need to update read/ seen status of getstream notification feed via rest api or php sdk. Would be a great help if someone can help me out on this.

Reason is, I'm using rest api to integrate getstream with a flutter app Im developing. I though it would be easier than using native sdk as Im only using small amount of features

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own questions as this was real tough to find,

https://getstream.io/docs/flat_feeds/?language=php&q=mark_seen#notification_feeds